# What are the potential problems of a MongoDB reserved collection name?

Tags: mongodb

I've named a MongoDB collection "version". Now when entering the following command:

> db.version.find()

I get the following response:

```
Sat Oct 05 23:22:30.943 TypeError: Object function (){
    return this.serverBuildInfo().version;
} has no method 'find'
```

I can bypass this problem using:

```
db.getCollection("version").find()
```

My question: I would really like to use the name "version" and can live with the db.getCollection(...) command, but are there other implications ? What other problems a collection named "version" could generate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beyond conflict with the shell commands?  None.

From the MongoDB [reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/) on the subject:

> Collection names should begin with an underscore or a letter
>   character, and cannot:
>
> - contain the $.
> - be an empty string (e.g. "").
> - contain the null character.
> - begin with the `system.` prefix. (Reserved for internal use.)
> - ***In the mongo shell, use db.getCollection() to specify collection names
>     that might interact with the shell or are not valid JavaScript.***

Emphasis mine.